# Why Remove support for ParNew+SerialOld and DefNew+CMS in the future？

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

Comment: https://www.jclarity.com/2013/12/11/poorly-chosen-java-hotspot-garbage-collection-flags-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: Not sure anymore if that post answers your actual question. But I guess it makes for good reading if you are into JVM garbage collection details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasons and alternatives for users are outlined in [JEP 173](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/173).

It boils down to maintenance overhead for rarely used combinations of young/old collectors.

See also [JEP 214](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/214), about the future removal of the deprecated combinations.